# How do I access $ {} inside a # {} variable?

Tags: node.js, variables, pug

[image]

I want to access `itemInfoData.items` using an index:

```
$('#tbody').append(`<td>#{itemInfoData.items[${i}].server}</td>`);
```

but This error occurs.

> Syntax Error: Unexpected token

How do I access $ {} inside a # {} variable?

itemInfoData is the local variable passed to pug in `res.render`.

Comment: Please post you code, not an image of it.

Comment: What is `i` in your code? does your code work when just using  `itemInfoData.items` with some hard coded key passed to it? Can you please provide these details.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html).

As you're already in an interpolated expression there's no need to add another inside:

```
#{itemInfoData.items[i].server}
```